# Set ng-checked value from two expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here are my controller scopes

```
$scope.all = [
    {'ID':'1','NAME':'BOB','BMW':1,'AUDI':'0'},
    {'ID':'2','NAME':'PETE','BMW':'0','AUDI':'1'}
];

$scope.cars = [
    {'ID':'1','CAR':'BMW'},
    {'ID':'2','CAR':'AUDI'}
];
```

Here is my view

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th ng-repeat="c in cars">{{c.CAR}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="u in all">
        <td>{{ u.NAME }}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="c in cars">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{ u.c.CAR }}">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now i want to check the checkboxes based on the value of the cars `ng-checked="{{ u.c.CAR }}"` but i am not able to set it. And i am not getting any errors in firebug. Does angularjs provide such expressions or not? If now, what is other solution?? I want it to be set in the view itself

Update: I should have done this long back. Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QUsJB/)

Comment: Please check my update question with jsfiddle

Comment: You can just remove the curly braces, there's no need for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to resolve the `1` or `0` as `true` and `false`.  You should be able to do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="u in all">
    <td>{{ u.NAME }}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="c in cars">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="u[c.CAR] == 1">
    </td>
</tr>
```

*Note: you don't need to interpolate `{  }` inside `ng-checked`.

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qwg4v/).

Comment: I tried your solution but not working. Could you please check my jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your expression is just a bit off:

```
ng-checked="u[c.car] == 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve your problem revisiting your ng-repeat, if you write something like u as object in all, instead of u in all, you can use the u items in the way you're trying to, whatever take a look at this module of angular ui [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) it has a lot of option and it can acomplish your needs

@vishwakumar that's a plunker for you, youneed to download the css too to setting in the right way the row height but that's a way to solve you're problem and trust me, ng-grid can solve a lot of problems other than that [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJlJTGCQttthDSzeEuqU?p=preview)
EDIT
i have put on it the check too, if you need the comment to understand the code in the plunker write it in the comment of the answer and i'll do it

Comment: Seems interesting. Could you please show me with an example or demo specific to my question??

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your expression. Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="u in all">
    <td>{{ u.NAME }}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="c in cars">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="u[c.CAR].toString() == '1'">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would also suggest ensuring that your data is either all strings or all integers, rather than a mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

That is your answer.  You have some lame quote in your "all" list!  Plus, your ng-repeat template is wrongly written.

Your $scope should be initialized as

```
    function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.all = [
            {'ID':'1','NAME':'BOB','BMW':'1','AUDI':'0'},
            {'ID':'2','NAME':'PETE','BMW':'0','AUDI':'1'}
        ];

        $scope.cars = [
            {'ID':'1','CAR':'BMW'},
            {'ID':'2','CAR':'AUDI'}
        ];
    }
```

Your $scope's DOM should be

```
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="DefaultCtrl">
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th ng-repeat="c in cars">{{c.CAR}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="u in all">
            <td>{{ u.NAME }}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="c in u.BMW">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{ c }}">
            <td ng-repeat="c in u.AUDI">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{ c }}">
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
    </div>
```

Your answer should be [image: Click to see picture !!!]